# How to pass a method to qsort?

Tags: c++

There is a class that contains some data and it sorts them at some point of time. I use `qsort()` and I'd like to keep the comparing function within the class as a method. The question is how to pass a method to `qsort()` so that the compiler (g++) don't throw any warnings?

Attempt 1:

```
int Data::compare_records(void * rec_1, void * rec_2){
  // [...]
}

void Data::sort(){
  qsort(records, count, sizeof(*records), &Data::compare_records);
}
```

This way generates an error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (Data::*)(const void*, const void*)’ to ‘int (*)(const void*, const void*)’ for argument ‘4’ to ‘void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))’
```

Attempt 2 :

```
void Data::sort(){
  qsort(
    records, count, sizeof(*records),
    (int (*)(const void*, const void*)) &Data::compare_records
  );
}
```

This way generates a warning:

```
warning: converting from ‘int (Data::*)(const void*, const void*)’ to ‘int (*)(const void*, const void*)’
```

How to do it the right way then?

Comment: You should not be using `qsort` in C++. Never. Ever. `std::sort` is *faster*, more flexible and typesafe, `qsort` is none of that. Just forget `qsort` ever existed, at least unless you ever get to environment where you need to use plain C.

Comment: You should use `std::sort` instead of the `C` function `qsort`. The fact that this function takes `void *` arguments defeats most of the optimization that a compiler could make (conf H. Sutter).

Comment: In fact if `Data` has non-trivial copy constructor or non-trivial destructor, using `qsort` is Undefined Behaviour. It can do anything at all, vomiting all over memory being one of the more pleasant possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the function as `&Data::compare_records`, but you should pass it as `Data::compare_records` and also make it `static`

Comment: The two are equivalent in C++, and pedantically, the first version is actually more expressive to the intention.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. Actually, the function name is already a pointer to a function, that's what I remembered and maybe that's why I forgot, that `&` is not forbidden there

Answer (score 7):

If you must use `qsort` and not `std::sort` (**recommended**), declaring the member method as `static` should be enough.

Comment: I would really make the "(recommended)" stronger. `std::sort` is *faster*, more flexible *and* typesafe.

Comment: And larger (generates more binary code). But if you care about that, you're probably not using C++ in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `qsort` in C++. Use `std::sort` and `boost/std::bind`. Member function-pointer cannot been converted to function-pointer. Your method should be `static`, or it should be `free function`.

see [Is the type of “pointer-to-member-function” different from “pointer-to-function”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code may also help as a hint, for std::sort despite the fact I Use Qt's qSort()

Functors can be very cool.

```
struct randomWSort
{
    SatoshiGame* This;
    randomWSort(SatoshiGame* g){This=g;}
    bool operator()(QString& a, QString& b)
    {
        return This->randomWSort(a,b);
    }
};

bool SatoshiGame::randomWSort(QString& a, QString& b)
{
    return rand->rnd() %2;
}

QString SatoshiGame::getRandomString(QStringList words)
{
    qSort(words.begin(), words.end(), ::randomWSort(this) );
    return words.at(0);
}
```